# Retrofit returning zero while parsing JSON using JACKSON

Tags: android, json, jackson, retrofit

Retrofit is returning Zero for some type of JSON variables.The Class is

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Temperature implements Parcelable {

@JsonProperty("day")
public float dayAvg;

@JsonProperty("min")
public float minTemp;

@JsonProperty("max")
public float maxTemp;

@JsonProperty("night")
public float nightTemp;

@JsonProperty("eve")
public float eveningTemp;

@JsonProperty("morn")
public float morningTemp;

public Temperature(){

}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeFloat(this.dayAvg);
    dest.writeFloat(this.minTemp);
    dest.writeFloat(this.maxTemp);
    dest.writeFloat(this.nightTemp);
    dest.writeFloat(this.eveningTemp);
    dest.writeFloat(this.morningTemp);
}

private Temperature(Parcel in) {
    this.dayAvg = in.readFloat();
    this.minTemp = in.readFloat();
    this.maxTemp = in.readFloat();
    this.nightTemp = in.readFloat();
    this.eveningTemp = in.readFloat();
    this.morningTemp = in.readFloat();
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Temperature> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Temperature>() {
    public Temperature createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Temperature(source);
    }

    public Temperature[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Temperature[size];
    }
};
```

}

Issue is that `maxTemp` and `minTemp` are coming as zero when using Retrofit.But if I directly use Jackson. I am getting correct values for `maxTemp` and `minTemp`

Comment: jackson with retrofit?

Comment: @njzk2 Yes.Retrofit uses either GSON or JACKSON for parsing JSON.

Comment: ok. but `SerializedName` is a gson annotation, afaik

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the `@JsonProperty` . With this annotation we also need to use the `@SerializedName` Annotation.